# Which editions of Visual Studio actually include a profiler for C++?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm really confused by all the ambiguity from all the sources I've been looking at. Can anyone give a clear answer to which editions of Visual Studio that actually includes a profiler for native C++ applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx

premium and ultimate not pro or express.